# Get a Post Loop based on Logged in User information into a Shortcode

Tags: loop, shortcode, query-posts, wp-user-query

I have a follower button on users profiles where users can follow other users. I have a page template that shows all posts by users the currently logged in user follows. I would like to create a shortcode [following_loop] for this instead and add the query to the functions.php. I can't get the shortcode to work.

Here is the page template that I was using. How can I get this into the shortcode?

```
function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('following_users', 'following_users_function');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
function following_users_function () {

    $currentloggedinuser = get_current_user_id();

  // Get array containing only the user_id1 values.

  $followers = $wpdb->get_col(
    $wpdb->prepare(
      "SELECT user_id1 FROM {$wpdb->prefix}followers WHERE user_id2 = %d",
      $currentloggedinuser      
    )   
  );

  sort($followers); // or apply sorting in the query above

  // Directly echo the imploded array. 
  echo implode(', ', $followers);

  $args = array(
    'author__in'=> $followers, //use the array we got from the query
    'post_type' => 'post'
  );
    
    if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
         $return_string = '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
      endwhile;
   endif;
    
    wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't get the shortcode to work.

So I see there's a `$args` in your code, so if you actually want posts that match those args, then you can [create a secondary query/loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#creating-secondary-queries-and-loops) like so: (replace all code from the `if (have_posts()) :` to the `wp_reset_query();`):

```php
global $post;

// Create a secondary query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Define the variable which stores the shortcode output
$return_string = '';

// Run the custom loop and append the output to $return_string. Remember, no echo!
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $return_string .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata(); // restore the $post global - don't call wp_reset_query()
endif;
```

And be sure to add `global $wpdb;` at the top in your function because currently the variable is not defined in that function.

*Also, please **do not echo** anything in shortcode functions because for example it can invalidate REST API responses and causes the block editor to fail in saving the post! So be sure to remove that `echo implode(...);`.*

Comment: You are a genius :) Thank you so much. This works perfectly. I am still learning Wordpress and your comments are always so detailed and useful. Thank you again so much, I really appreciate your assistance :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: PS: I've just revised my answer - I mainly moved `wp_reset_postdata();` to inside the `if` block, so be sure to do the same. And I also added a link to the 1st paragraph, so I suggest you to check it out to learn out more about The Loop. =)